# DotNetInstaller won't resume where it left off after reboot

Tags: resume, reboot, dotnetinstaller

I am stuck on this one. After an exe component which requires reboot is executed, the dotnetinstaller script forces a reboot. However after reboot it starts right from beginning not after the step which required rebooting.

These are the details:
DotNetInstaller Version: 2.13
Properties:

```
Auto_Continue_on_reboot = true
must_reboot_required = false
must_reboot = true
returnCodes_reboot = 3010
```

Registry Values:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run:
Name: Default                       Value: (Value Not Set)
Name: dotNetInstaller.exe     Value: "C:\Installer\dotNetInstaller.exe" /Reboot
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was answered by Daniel Doubrovkine in the dotnetinstaller Google Group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dotnetinstaller/aNyBMwBt9DU).

> That is by design. DNI is a state machine, and it will restart in the
>   beginning every time you run it.  You should implement install checks
>   in your installer to make sure you're not reinstalling something that
>   has already been installed.